# Python json.loads lead to Extra data Exception

Tags: python, json

This is how my file look like:

[image]

**My code**

```
import json

with open(r'c:\sample.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

And I got this error:

```
Extra data: line 18 column 2 (char 294)
```

What does it mean ? what extra data ?

Comment: Your json file is invalid.Each file should only contain one json.You may need to put them in am array. For example, add `[` in the front and `]` in the end.

Comment: I built it form string so what should i change here ?

Comment: What did you build from a string? Your code shows that you call `json.load()` which reads an open file. There don't seem to be any strings involved.

Answer (score 2):

a json file can only be one data structure, if you want to put multiple dicts in it, then you can put them in a list

```json
[
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
]
```

Comment: I build it form string that comes from list, what i need to change here in the structure ?

Answer (score 1):

The structure should look like this:

```json
[
  {
    "bat":"0",
    ...
  },
  {
    "bat":"0",
    ...
  },
]
```